# Calculate next work day based on custom holiday calendar using java

Tags: java, date, calendar

Im trying to calculate Next Working day by adding specific number of days based on custom holiday calendar from database.

Eg:
- Current Day:9th March
- Holidays: 10th March, 12th March , 13th March
- Days to add: 5

The result should fetch me: 17th Match

Is there a easy way to handle this in java?

I have the followingcode written

```
public class TestNextWorkinDay {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TestNextWorkinDay d = new TestNextWorkinDay();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date fDate = sdf.parse("2019-04-09");

        //adding holidays to List
        String date1="2019-04-10";
        String date2="2019-04-12";
        String date3="2019-04-13";

        ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
        dates.add(date1);
        dates.add(date2); 
        dates.add(date3);
        String dueDate = d.getNextWorkingDay(fDate ,5, dates);
        System.out.println("due Date " + dueDate);
    }


    public String getNextWorkingDay(Date fDate,int bday , ArrayList<String> dates){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(fDate);
        SimpleDateFormat fdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        while(bday > 0){
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
           String date= fdate.format(cal.getTime());
            if(checkIfNonWorkingDay(date , dates)){
                bday--;
            }
        }
        return fdate.format(cal.getTime());
    }

    public boolean checkIfNonWorkingDay(String cal , ArrayList<String> dates){

        if(dates.contains(cal)){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }





}
```

Comment: Can you give more precise input?
How 9 + 5 is 17th? I don't get that.

Here 17th March is Sunday so it's not working day.

Comment: @Shaq; Holiday is maintained in custom table. So in my case, Sunday is working day. 11th, 14, 15, 16, 17 are working. So if we ignore 10, 12 and 13, the next work day would be 17.

Comment: Your if condition to decrement ``bday`` looks reversed.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated (the first in particular notoriously troublesome). Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. Our application is running with java7. I see that LocalDate was introduced as part of java8.

Comment: It was, @kamathsachin7, but `LocalDate` and most if java.time have been backported to Java 6 and 7 in [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). So consider adding that to your project for the future-proof and programmer-friendly solution.

Comment: @OleV.V. point noted. I will make necessary changes for future proof solution. Thank you for the suggestion !!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Working Days in a Month]

If you have the custom table design something like this (March Month of 2019).

1. Hold the month data in a data structure.
2. From the day (i.e. 9th March) start adding the next working day (which is marked as 1). Index of the 5th working day should give you day of the month.

Comment: Why would you record dates in that way? This is unreadable and not restricted by the datatype itself, which is a bad practice.

Comment: I have stored the non working days as string. I cannot have it store with binaries. And as @Alexis mentioned, this is a bad practice.